Start job no more then once a day on Jenkins
I have a project build task that starts every 4 hours, if it is ok, task trigger another test task. Now I want to start a new test task (old should work too), but no more than once a day.
I would also like to clarify, new test task should not be started if build task is not stable. But if the next build on the same day is successful and the new task has not yet been launched on that day, then it needs to be launched (trying to trigger this task once a day and see if the build is successful is not my option).
I'm new to Jenkins and don't understand which exists plugins. I know that I can try to write a bash script, but it will be too cumbersome and I don’t want to support it.

I understand you don't want to support a bash script, but this kind of custom behaviour requires some logic and I'm not aware of any plugin that would do exactly what you want. That being said the logic is rather simple, you just need to check the last build start time:
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob

import java.time.Duration
import java.time.Instant

def isLastBuildOverADayOld(String jobFullName) {
  def lastBuiltStart = Jenkins.get().getItemByFullName(jobFullName, WorkflowJob).lastBuild.time.toInstant()
  def now = Instant.now()
  return Duration.between(lastBuiltStart, now).toDays() > 1
}

